# Converting a string with comma separated value in a tree in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a csv file that contains a field with a category tree in a comma separated format like this:

```
MotherCategory, ChildCategory1, ChildCategory2, ecc.
```

Some records contains only a category, other ones two, other ones three or more.

I would like to be able to store in my db all the unique categories and organise every record with a `parentid` scheme where the `parentid` value is the `id` of the category one level up.

At the end I should have something like:

```
id: 1, catname: MotherCategory, parentid: NULL
id: 2, catname: ChildCategory1, parentid: 1
id: 3, catname: ChildCategory2, parentid: 2
```

I've already filtered the data removing duplicates with `array_unique()`, next using `explode()` I am able to separate the values and I was counting the values and separating the groups basing on the length of the resultant arrays to build a tree, but I think that at the moment I am missing something to get my final result.

I've the following code. Can someone please give me a hint to solve the problem?

```
$cats = array_of_comma_separated_values;

foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $catarray[] = explode(",",$cat);
}

//first level
$level1 = array_filter ($catarray, function($item) {
    if (count($item) == 1) { return true; } return false; 
});

//second level
$level2 = array_filter ($catarray, function($item) {
    if (count($item) == 2) { return true; } return false;
});

$level3 = array_filter ($catarray, function($item) { 
    if (count($item) == 3) { return true; } return false;
});

$level4 = array_filter ($catarray, function($item) {
    if (count($item) == 4) { return true; } return false;
});

$level5 = array_filter ($catarray, function($item) {
    if (count($item) == 5) { return true; } return false;
});

$level6 = array_filter ($catarray, function($item) {
    if (count($item) == 6) { return true; } return false;
});

$level7 = array_filter ($catarray, function($item) {
    if (count($item) == 7) { return true; } return false;
});
```

This gives me several arrays that i've to iterate to achieve what i'm looking for.

Now thanks to the suggestion from **Kovlar** I'm working on something based on `array_pop()` and `array_replace_recurive()`.

I've edited the post because maybe I was not so clear.

Comment: Can you add what your currently have?

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far to get help from SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the use of `array_replace_recursive()` to simplify the tree-merging :)

```php
// $tree will contain the tree at the end of the script
$tree = [];
// we treat each row of the csv one by one
foreach($csv_rows as $row) {
    // first, we split the string into an array
    $root_to_leaf = explode(',', $row['root_to_leaf']);
    // this is the "leaf" we want to append to the tree
    $leaf = [array_pop($root_to_leaf) => $row['value']];
    // we rebuild the path from the leaf to the root
    while(!empty($root_to_leaf)) {
        // add the next branching toward the root
        $leaf = [array_pop($root_to_leaf) => $leaf];
    }
    // we append the leaf to the tree
    $tree = array_replace_recursive($tree, $leaf);
}
```

Comment: I'm working on a solution based on array_pop and array_replace_recursive, but your code returns me several syntax errors.

Comment: The errors regards the use of square brackets for setting an array value, i'm rewriting the code using array($key => $value) instead

Comment: sorry for that, didn't knew which version of PHP you were using ^_^